# Power Pivot Many to Many Relationship

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Please help.

Simply put I am trying to get the calculated column in table 3 to display the participation number from table 2. Need it to filter by name and date.

The formula in the calculated column is my attempt which doesn't work.

Any help or questions would be appreciated.

[image: Data Tables With Attempted Calculated Column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

`=LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[Participation Num],Table2[Name],Table3[Name],Table2[Date],Table3[Date])`

Comment: Not a problem @Qwerty. Looking at your screenshots of your table I imagine you could probably set your data model up to make things a bit easier/simpler too

Comment: Any feedback would be happily received especially if it makes it easier / simpler. I have also posted a follow up question if you fancy having a look. Much appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228041/powerpivot-lookupvalue-with-conditions