# PowerPivot FILTER With Conditions

Tags: excel, dax

I have two tables as shown in the image below.

***What I want to do is get Table 3 to look up table 2 and show what exercise was being done during the relevant minutes.***

For example Participant A on the 01/04/2020 did 4 runs (Run 1, 2, 3 & 4) each lasting 5 mins. So in table 3 Min 01,02,03,04,05 would have Run 1 in the 'added column' and Min 06,07,08,09,10 would have Run 2 etc.

I have added in the Total exercise Y/N column as the 'Total exercise' will dictate the start and end of exercise for each participant in that session / on that day.

[image: Table 2 & Table 3]

Comment: Can you post (eg dropbox, google drive etc)  file with your current data model setup and some dummy data